# Updating value on django model object does not update value on related foreign key model

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models, House and Room where Room has a foreign key to House:

```
class House(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Room(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rooms')
```

When I run the following test, for some reason the colors are not matching, even though the ids do.  Can someone help figure out why?

```
def test_color_change(self):
    h = House(name='new house')
    h.save()

    r = h.rooms.create(
        name='living room',
        color='blue'
    )
    r2 = h.rooms.get(name='living room')
    r2.color = 'green'
    r2.save()
    self.assertEqual(r.id, r2.id)
    self.assertEqual(r2.color, r.color)
```

I've been looking at the django documentation for [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/), but haven't been able to figure it out. I would have expected r and r2 to be pointing to the same object, but apparently they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"r" contains a Python instance of `Room` created with the data pull from DB at the time of the query, it is not some kind of reference to a row of the database. When you update this row by changing the color to "green", the "r" variable does not get updated.

Your test should be:

```
def test_color_change(self):
    h = House(name='new house')
    h.save()

    r = h.rooms.create(
        name='living room',
        color='blue'
    )
    r.color = 'green'
    r.save()
    r2 = h.rooms.get(name='living room')
    self.assertEqual(r.id, r2.id)
    self.assertEqual(r2.color, r.color)
```

However, I don't see what this test is supposed to achieve since you're literally testing the ORM.

Comment: The test was just to illustrate what I found confusing, but your first sentence cleared it up!